# GoogleDrive: Cannot move file outside the folder

Tags: google-drive

I have nested folders in my google drive.

```
My Drive/
    ...
Shared with Me/
    Folder1/
        folder11/
            filex
            filey 
        folder12/
            filez
```

I want to move filey in to folder12 but in the current web interface "move to" only allows me to move this file outside of shared to My Drive.

I created the folders 11 and 12 and put the files inside there so their shouldn't be any permission issues. Is there a way I can achieve this problem without downloading the drive desktop client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to move the file, you'll need to add it to "My Drive". Until you do that it's only shared with you and you don't have rights to do much of anything with it.

Click the "Add to My Drive" icon/link. Then you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can see NEW button left side through which you can create new folder and file upload and etc...

Below that you need to expand My Drive and expand your Folder1 and open folder11.

Inside the folder11 you can see your file filey right side select that using mouse move and drag it to the folder12 which you can see in expanded under folder1.

[image]

That's it you can have your filey in folder12 from folder11.

Comment: the folder is in shared with me folder. There is no arrow you are talking about in shared with me folder.

Comment: You can see the files that shared with you in incoming menu and you can add it in your drive by clicking add to my drive and do the above process you in your drive.